# What does each field of netstat -ano mean?

Tags: netstat

```
tcp        0      0 219.155.32.195:8888     221.137.227.51:5943     TIME_WAIT   timewait (58.45/0/0)
tcp        0      0 219.155.32.195:8888     221.137.227.51:5936     TIME_WAIT   timewait (59.36/0/0)
tcp        0   2944 219.155.32.195:8888     221.137.227.51:5937     FIN_WAIT1   on (0.35/0/0)
```

Especially for the 3rd row,what does `0` , `FIN_WAIT1`, `on` and `(0.35/0/0)` mean respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 & 3rd columns are receive and send queues, respectively.  (`0 2944` above)  That's basically the number of <strike>packets</strike> bytes waiting to be sent (2944) or received (0).

FIN_WAIT is the standard TCP state of the open port.  Specifically, that's an actively closed connection.  (more info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137984))  The client has sent its FIN packet, but hasn't received a FIN-ACK back yet.

The last column is a bit more complex.  It's timer information related to the specific state the connection is in.

Comment: Here (on Linux) Recv-Q and Send-Q are # of bytes, not # of packets.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

What netstat you are running matters, I am assuming this is Windows Netstat, look here for more info: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true

There are several steps in setting up and tearing down a TCP connection. The TCP Connection State column just tells you where in the process that socket is at the moment.

[This](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-2.htm) explains TCP Connection states in more detail.